# How this obfuscated C line prints "EMIL"?

Tags: c, deobfuscation

Can you explain how does the following code work?

```
main(O){10<putchar(4^--O?77-(15&5128>>4*O):10)&&main(2+O);}
```

Output:

```
EMIL
```

You can test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/xBWGpY). I have found this line on [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind)'s profile.

Comment: The C++ tag is wrong, because this isn't a well-formed C++ program (And I am not sure about it being a well-formed C program either)

Comment: http://www.hellkvist.org/funstuff/haiku/haiku.php

Comment: 5 upvotes and counting? Is that for real?

Comment: Why not ask @unwind himself? (I agree it is an interesting question)

Comment: @SList how so? You can easily run through it to see what it does - there are no interesting concepts in there, if you know the very basics of the C language (yes, basics - what the operators do & default `int` type for variables declared without a type).

Comment: It is just fun, Luchian. I don't understand why this harmless question has attracted scorn and bile, instead of an answer for the questioner.

Comment: @S List Because, primarily, it adds nothing to the SO knowledge base. As Luchian says, you can unpick this trivially. Yes that can be fun; rather like solving a soduku or a crossword. But on this site it has no place: what's stopping someone from submitting countless examples of obfuscation?

Comment: Nobody is submitting countless examples.  This was on someone's profile.  Stop taking it so seriously.

Comment: @S List, not yet. But 4 upvotes will certainly not disincentivise someone from doing so.

Comment: `main(_){putchar(117-(31&446470>>5*(_-1))-!(5^_)*107)&3^2&&main(++_);}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deobfuscation can easily be done in a step-by-step basis.

White-space always helps:

```
main(O)
{
  10 < putchar(4 ^ --O ? 77 - (15 & 5128 >> 4 * O)
                       : 10)
  && main(2+O);
}
```

Add a variable:

```
main(O)
{
  int i = 4 ^ --O ? 77 - (15 & 5128 >> 4 * O)
                  : 10;
  i = putchar(i);
  10 < i && main(2+O);
}
```

Replace `?:` with if-else:

```
main(O)
{
  int i;
  if (4 ^ --O)
    i = 77 - (15 & 5128 >> 4 * O)
  else
    i = 10;
  i = putchar(i);
  10 < i && main(2 + O);
}
```

Replace `&&` with if:

```
main(O)
{
  int i;
  if (4 ^ --O)
    i = 77 - (15 & 5128 >> 4 * O)
  else
    i = 10;
  i = putchar(i);
  if (10 < i)
    main(2 + O);
}
```

Brackets for clarity:

```
main(O)
{
  int i;
  if (4 ^ --O)
    i = 77 - (15 & (5128 >> (4 * O)))
  else
    i = 10;
  i = putchar(i);
  if (10 < i)
    main(2 + O);
}
```

From here it's a simple case of applying basic C knowledge of operators.

Run through the code: (initial parameter of `main` is 1, [we can check this](http://ideone.com/fj9bII))

```
main(1)
  4 ^ 0 = 4 = true
    5128 >> 4 * 0 = 5128
    15 & 5128 = 8
    i = 77 - 8 = 69
  putchar(69) -> 'E'
  10 < 69
    call main(2+0)
main(2)
  ...
```

How whomever wrote it came up with it? Well, to my knowledge, that's mostly a mystery when it comes to obfuscated code.

Answer (score 6):

If you translate the code into nicer C, then it could look like this:

```
int main(int i)
{
    int ch;

    i--;
    if (i ^ 4)
        ch = 77 - (15 & (5128 >> (4 * i))); 
    else
        ch = 10;

    ch = putchar(ch);
    if (ch > 10)
        main(i + 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

- `main()` is called recursively for each character.
- `putchar()` on success returns the character is just wrote to the console.
- Printing a newline (ASCII code 10) is the condition to stop the recursion.
- The original code depends on the old C rule that undeclared variable are of type `int`.
- The variable `i` has the value 1 on the first call (it's in fact the `argc` argument).
- For the first `if`, the variable `i` has the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in the five iterations. For the value 4, the if condition becomes false and the newline (ASCII 10) is used.
- The expression `77 - (15 & (5128 >> (4 * i)))` produces the ASCII codes for the letters E, M, I, L for the `i` values 0, 1, 2, 3.